# Как обратиться к методу экземпляра класса из другого класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

задача такая - создается чат, к нему подключается 2 клиента и они отправляют сообщения, необходимо, чтобы сообщения сохранялись в экземпляре класса `Chat`.

В методе `send` класса `Human` или класса `Robot` я должен обратиться к экземпляру чата, но я не понимаю как это сделать, ведь при проектировании я знаю только о существовании класса `Chat`.

```py
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def send(self, sms):
        Chat.communication(sms)


class Robot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def send(self, sms):
        Chat.communication(sms)


class Chat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chat_history = ""

    def connect_human(self, human: Human):
        self.name_human = human.name

    def connect_robot(self, robot: Robot):
        self.name_robot = robot.name

    def communication(self, sms):
        self.chat_history += sms


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing

    chat_100 = Chat()
    karl = Human("Karl")
    bot = Robot("R2D2")
    chat_100.connect_human(karl)
    chat_100.connect_robot(bot)
    karl.send("Hi! What's new?")
    bot.send("Hello, human. Could we speak later about it?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к методу класса `Chat` как к статическому, хотя он таковым не является. Вам необходимо каким-либо образом передать объект Вашего класса `Chat` в объекты классов `Human` и `Robot`. Например, так:

```py
class Human:
    def __init__(self, chat, name):
        self.name = name
        self.chat = chat

    def send(self, sms):
        chat.communication(sms)


class Robot:
    def __init__(self, chat, name):
        self.name = name
        self.chat = chat

    def send(self, sms):
        chat.communication(sms)


class Chat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chat_history = ""

    def connect_human(self, human: Human):
        self.name_human = human.name

    def connect_robot(self, robot: Robot):
        self.name_robot = robot.name

    def communication(self, sms):
        self.chat_history += sms


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing

    chat_100 = Chat()
    karl = Human(chat_100, "Karl")
    bot = Robot(chat_100, "R2D2")
    chat_100.connect_human(karl)
    chat_100.connect_robot(bot)
    karl.send("Hi! What's new?")
    bot.send("Hello, human. Could we speak later about it?")
```

В таком случае бессмысленно передавать в чат объекты `carl` и `bot`, если с ними не планируется работа в дальнейшем.

В общем:

1. Чтобы вызвать нестатический метод класса, в любом случае необходимо
   иметь объект этого класса.
2. Я не проверял и не исправлял Ваш код с точки зрения правильного ООП, т.к. это тема для отдельного обсуждения. Однако могу сказать, что Вам следует задуматься, а лучше почитать соответствующую литературу о правильном проектировании классов и предоставляемых ими интерфейсов, потому что в данный момент взаимное включение классов `Human` и `Chat` друг в друга вызывает опасения (та же ситуация с `Chat` и `Robot`).

Вариант 2:

В ситуации, когда код `main` менять нельзя, следует сделать что-то наподобие такого:

```py
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def connect_to_chat(chat):
        self.chat = chat

    def send(self, sms):
        chat.communication(sms)


class Robot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def connect_to_chat(chat):
        self.chat = chat

    def send(self, sms):
        chat.communication(sms)


class Chat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chat_history = ""

    def connect_human(self, human: Human):
        self.name_human = human.name
        human.connect_to_chat(self)

    def connect_robot(self, robot: Robot):
        self.name_robot = robot.name
        robot.connect_to_chat(self)

    def communication(self, sms):
        self.chat_history += sms


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing

    chat_100 = Chat()
    karl = Human("Karl")
    bot = Robot("R2D2")
    chat_100.connect_human(karl)
    chat_100.connect_robot(bot)
    karl.send("Hi! What's new?")
    bot.send("Hello, human. Could we speak later about it?")
```

Comment: Я это понимаю, что я неправильно делаю обращение. Но я не могу передать экземпляр чата клиенту при создании клиента. Может когда я добавляю клиента в чат, то сообщить ему как-то экземпляр этого чата?

Comment: @ChapeauClaque поясните, пожалуйста, причину невозможности передать экземпляр чата клиенту.

Comment: @ChapeauClaque В крайнем случае можно сделать что-то наподобие метода `connect_client_to_chat(chat)` для клиента и передавать в него необходимый чат уже после создания объекта.

Comment: Всё, что находится после `if __name__ == '__main__'` это проверка выполнения задания и её менять нельзя. Мне нужно только реализовать классы.

Comment: @ChapeauClaque Сейчас допишу в ответ.

Comment: В примерах подобного шаблона приводят [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) Часть действий мне сложно понять, поэтому начал строить свой велосипед.

Comment: @ChapeauClaque Представил ещё один вариант в ответе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96543/discussion-between-chapeauclaque-and-v-mor).